# Why does my object follow the path, but with a weird offset?

Tags: animation, constraints

I'm modelling a fictional solar system, and one plan has a very eccentric orbit. So I've set the planet's constraint to "Follow Path." It moves, but not along the orbit. See the screenshot below.

[image: The animation workspace for the system in question]

Comment: Make sure that the origin is at the center of the planet and reset the planet location (alt G)

Comment: Try zeroing the objects location :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the origin is at the center of the planet (<kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*, and reset the planet location (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>).

Comment: I did both of these, just now, and the planet is still offset from its orbit, though the offset is now parallel to the X axis instead of at some weird and variable angle to it.

Comment: please share your file (with only the problematic objects): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Done. https://blend-exchange.com/b/Yr8M8LlZ

Comment: You've keyframed the location of the object, which keeps it far from the scene center, you need to delete these keyframes, then Alt G to bring your object back to the scene center

Comment: It worked. Thank you!